# "Custom Date Picker" does not take care of end date in Chronograf Dashboard

Tags: chronograf

When I take "Custom date Picker", the begin date works but the end date is ignored, always "now" no matter what I enter.

[image: Chronograf Costum Data Picker Problem]

But, when I use the default graphics in "Host Name" tab, it is working with no issue.

What I am doing wrong?

I use Chronograf 1.3.10-0

Edit: Same problem with Chronograf 1.4.0-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the query. The query constructor does not add automatiquely the end date, or the :upperDashboardTime: variable:

```
SELECT mean("usage_user") AS "usage_user" FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."cpu" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND time < :upperDashboardTime: AND "host"=:host-name: GROUP BY :interval: FILL(null)
```

We have to add manually "AND time < :upperDashboardTime:".

More information in this issue : https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/issues/2760